# How do I read a log file in text format and display only the required content?

Tags: vb.net

I want to read the log file which is in the text format from the folder where the logs are generated by other application. The problem is I can read the whole file but I want to print only certain part of each line and the other problem is logs are generated for every 5 seconds and saved to the folder I want to automatically pick the new file every 5 second to show the updated data.

The log file data looks like this:

```
CPU Load : 4% 
---------- 

Memory Free : 7137 MB 
------------- 

Disk Space (Percent Free) : 
--------------------------- 
Disk C : 34% 
Disk D : 81% 
Disk E : 91% 
Disk F : 81% 
Disk S : 58% 
Disk W : 86% 

Services Status : 
----------------- 
Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 .......... : Running  
load_mnemonics_file ................ : Running  
load_vehicle_id_file ............... : Running  
Microsoft FTP Service .............. : Running  
OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListenerr1o21 : Running  
OracleServicer1o21 ................. : Running  
World Wide Web Publishing Service .. : Running  

Oracle : 
-------- 
Tablespace Index : 80% 
Tablespace Data  : 61% 
Sequence ....... : Correct
```

I want to load the percentages of the each lines.

Comment: There's tons of information around about reading text files and parsing the data. It's your responsibility to do the appropriate research, make an honest attempt and then post here if and only if you encounter a specific issue along the way, in which case you provide us with the relevant code and an explanation of how the behaviour that code doesn't meet your expectations. "This is what I want to do, you show me how" is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Look for File.ReadAllLines(), String.Contains(), and/or Regex.Match(). You should then try to develope your own solution

Comment: Looks like a _Do it for me_ question? You need to put in some efforts and write code first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Stream Reader

```
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
Dim strLine As String
objStreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\example\test.txt")
strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
```

Then you can start to read the file line for line and catch all Infos that you need

```
        Do While Not strLine Is Nothing
            If strLine.Contains("CPU Load") Then
                CPULoad = Replace(strLine, "CPU Load : ", "") 
                'this will replace the "CPU Load : " with nothing so that only the 4% get saved.
            End If
            'place for more
            Console.WriteLine(strLine)
            strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
        Loop
        'finish
        objStreamReader.Close()
```

I did it here in this example only with the CPU Load. Hope this brings you on the right track :)